# KeyDown/KeyUp 70-120ms delay. How to reduce?

Tags: javascript, canvas, keyboard, keyboard-events

We're developing **arcade** (a lot of action and speed) browser 2d-game using canvas.

Sometimes our testing players report us that there is a delay: player still moving 5-10 pixels away after keyup.

I've digged this issue, you can see yourself delay http://jsfiddle.net/C4ev3/7/ (try keydown/up any key as fast as you can). My results is from 70 to 120ms. And i think that's a lot. (FYI, our network latency is 10-20ms).

Any ideas how to reduce this delay?

**upd** i've noticed that on good hardware this delay is under 30-40ms. But i'm testing on core2duo, winxp, chrome 19 - it's not a P4 with IE6 :)

Comment: Anyway we could see more code? I doubt its the key event causing the issue. It could even have something to do with using jQuery to create a game where speed is important. Also network latency will not effect the game if its all client side.

Comment: if I leave the key pressed infinitely, i have 25-33

Comment: but my down/up arrow is not detected though...

Comment: Sorry, i've posted incorrect link. Updated question.

Comment: I am getting 24-32ms minimum. Really, I can't hit the spacebar any faster.

Comment: Theres no issue with the key events, its somewhere else in the code. Maybe in your game loop or rendering. Regardless the lag is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @Loktar i've changed to native js code. same results.

Comment: @Rene i think you have good hardware, but on core2duo, winxp, chrome 19 i have this results.

Comment: You need to remember that javascript is not threaded by nature but single queque.
So when there is something being processed like a canvas redraw, everything else is on hold for processing, even a keyup event.
So if your canvas redraw takes about 120ms that time is added before the keyup event is allowed to process.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets , on jsfiddle there is no canvas and other processing jobs :)

Comment: I know, but I manage by being quick to keep it at 16ms, at normal gaming pres it's about 54ms, but nothing else happens to cause a delay other than updating the value in the console(what is? half a millisecond?)
You should post code with canvas redraws that you use so that we can see where the holdup is... I think it's your canvas redraws which cause the delays.

Comment: Wow, let me say after rigorously pressing keys as fast as I freaking could The best I could do is 38ms... which I can believe is about the amount of time for the key to sit down, and the mechanical aspect of it (spring) to push it back out... maybe my touch (virtual keyboard) would be different... this is user latency...

Comment: Basically all your test shows us is how fast I can press and release a key on my keyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi one thing you could do is instead of using an anonymous function try using defined functions,

http://jsfiddle.net/C4ev3/10/ - for me this reported at 50-100 MS

However i would not recommend jQuery for Canvas Applications it's very big for the very little you using, you should try using native Javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/C4ev3/11/ - for me this reported 30-70 MS

**Javascript Threading**
One thing i noticed in the comments Javascript is not Multi-Threaded Well Urm-Arr,
it sort of is setInterval is Async not Sync, however affecting the window is a single thread E.G if you have a Class that has some number is it using a setInteval will use another thread and not have a problem altering the math however in the Task then requires a Draw on the page it will enter the bottom of the JS handle Que,

Certain parts of Javascript are on a different thread how ever any thing changing the page has to run on the Main Thread same as any Windows application if your thread want to change the Form your have to invoke the main thread to do it for you

however it is not multi-threaded like any thing else you cant just handle or abort at a given Wim like windows,

Other ASync Tasks include AJAX has the option to be both Async and Sync

**Updated to show my comment about FPS limiting:**

Please bear with me. This is linking to a project that is allready built to show the example:
so my Game is Completely OOP

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = elem.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle   = '#888';
context.lineWidth   = 4;
// Draw some rectangles.
context.fillRect(0,   0, 800, 600);
context.fillStyle = '#f00';

var ball = new Ball();
var leftPadel = new Padel(10, 60, 40, 120);
var rightPadel = new Padel(750, 520, 40, 120);

pong = new Pong();
pong.draw();

setTimeout("ball.move()", pong.redrawTime());
```

Inside my pong class is where all the main workings of the game goes but here are the FPS bit you need to see

```
this.fps = 30;
this.maxFPS = 60;

this.redrawTime = function(){
    return (1000 / this.fps)
}

this.lastDraw = (new Date)*1 - 1;
```

Then as you can see my Interval is on ball.move this calls the main pong class again on redraw at the End of the redraw i have the FPS checking and limiting code

```
this.fps = ((now=new Date) - this.lastDraw);
if(this.fps > this.maxFPS){
    this.fps = this.maxFPS;
}
this.lastDraw = (new Date)*1 - 1;
if(this.reporting = true){
    console.clear();
    console.log("FPS: "+this.fps.toFixed(1))
}
setTimeout("ball.move()", pong.redrawTime());
```

This then forces you to get the Best Possible FPS without queuing the Main Thread

Comment: eh, i've updated question with native js code a few minutes after posting question. i've the same results.

Comment: How are you drawing on the canvas?
I have worked with Canvas abit to teach my self built pong, and one the the best things you can do is have a FPS Monitor and just a setTimeout to match your FPS this will the prevent quing of drawing items witch might be your root cause let me dig out my Pong game and see i'm i can show you

Comment: i have updated my answer to try and reflect the FPS draw rate limiter and why this is reliant is down to the the fact your binding events to the page so if you have 30 draw request then the key down the 30 draw events occur before the key down event change is drawn

Comment: With workers you have true threading, but no access to the window object, with setinterval you can create a thread too but also without access to "window" objects to prevent quequeing.
It all depends on how long it takes to redraw the entire canvas that makes the holdup...
Workers are a step in the right direction, but i'm still desperately waiting for true threading with multiple changes possible to the dom from different threads...
So much for an eight core cpu and one browser... ;-)

Comment: You will never get your "True Threading" on the simple fact it is not possible to update the DOM simultaneously the same as a Windows Application cant do it you cant send multiple draws to the graphics card you will get the same error your experiencing in you current code base you would end up with screen drawing behind what is being requested, windows applications with all the Threading support they have can't just redraw different parts of the screen hence why you have to use a Invoke on the main thread so only that thread can draw and then to menny applications drawing causes graphics Lag

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**e.stopPropagation()**

> Stops the bubbling of an event to parent elements, preventing any
>   parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**e.preventDefault()**

> Prevents the browser from executing the default action. Use the method
>   isDefaultPrevented to know whether this method was ever called (on
>   that event object).

My min. results in Google chrome: 7ms